# Optional properties in a composite type (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

I've created a composite type which corresponds to my interface in Typescript for one of my Schemas; however I can't seem to find any documentation pointing on how to do that.

Here's an example:

```sql
CREATE TYPE PROMOTES AS (level INT, roles TEXT[], strip_roles BOOLEAN);
```

and I wish to mark `strip_roles` as an optional property, with a default value of `true`.

Is this even possible? And if yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: Iirc all attributes of a composite type are optional (nullable), and you would have to wrap it in a domain type to constrain them to be non-null.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the quick response; it's very much appreciated. I will give your suggestion a try and see if it suits my use case.